# Angular 5 - How to ignore updating one property of Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular2-observables

I'm developing a page to show some videos and user can like them. Videos and Likes are saved in a database and I used two angular services for set and get data. My problem is about setting and revoking likes on videos. after every request for set or revoke like on videos, the page data has been refreshed and loading videos upset the user. services are working fine and data sets to database correctly.

I just need to update like button color and likes count in the page. What is the solution to **ignore updating video links** that are fixed and never changed?

In below I put part of my codes:

**index.component.html :**

```
<mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let video of videos">
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>{{ video.title }}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>
            {{ video.description }}
        </mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <div class="video-container">
        <iframe class="video-frame" [src]="video.mediaSource | safe" allowFullScreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" ></iframe>
    </div>
    <mat-card-actions class="text-center">
        <button *ngIf="video.isLiked == true" mat-icon-button color="warn">
            <mat-icon (click)="revokeLike(1, video.id)">favorite</mat-icon>
        </button>

        <button *ngIf="video.isLiked == false" mat-icon-button class="grey_like">
            <mat-icon (click)="setLike(1, video.id)">favorite</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <span>{{ competition.likesCount }} Likes</span>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

**index.component.ts :**

```
export class ShowComponent implements OnInit {

    competitions:any;

    constructor(private service:VideoService, private http: HttpClient, private likeservice:LikeService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getVideos();
    }

    getVideos() {
        this.service.getVideos(1).subscribe(res => {
            this.videos = res;
        });
    }

    setLike(iid, video_id) {
        this.likeservice.setLike(iid, video_id).subscribe(
            () => this.getCompetitions()
        );
    }

    revokeLike(iid, video_id) {
        this.likeservice.revokeLike(iid, video_id).subscribe(
            () => this.getCompetitions()
        );
    }

}
```

**videos.service.ts :**

```
getVideos(id): Observable<any> {
    const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/videos/iid/' + id;
    return this
        .http
        .get(uri)
        .map(res => {
            return res;
        });
}
```

**like.service.ts :**

```
setLike(iid, competition_id) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/likes/set';
    const obj = {
        iid: iid,
        competition_id: competition_id
    };

    return this
        .http
        .post(uri, obj)
        .map(res =>
            console.log('Done'));
}

revokeLike(iid, competition_id) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/likes/revoke';
    const obj = {
        iid: iid,
        competition_id: competition_id
    };

    return this
        .http
        .post(uri, obj)
        .map(res =>
            console.log('Done'));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what the problem is. You want to skip making a new request after you like a video? Why don't you update the model directly?

Comment: Please add `setLike` and `revokeLike` functions

Comment: @Sravan two functions added!

Comment: @Andrew I want to update model after liking a video, as it works correctly now. but the problem is about updating model, update values in html and updating video iframes is not good for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information, I would do it like this. The idea is there's no need to requery the backend for the list of videos, since you know what/how changed and you only apply the change if you have an ok response.

Template:

```
<mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let video of videos">
    ...
    <button *ngIf="video.isLiked == true" mat-icon-button color="warn">
        <mat-icon (click)="revokeLike(video)">favorite</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <button *ngIf="video.isLiked == false" mat-icon-button class="grey_like">
        <mat-icon (click)="setLike(video)">favorite</mat-icon>
    </button>
    ...
</mat-card>
```

Controller:

```
export class ShowComponent implements OnInit {

    competitions:any;

    constructor(private service:VideoService, private http: HttpClient, private likeservice:LikeService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getVideos();
    }

    getVideos() {
        this.service.getVideos(1).subscribe(res => {
            this.videos = res;
        });
    }

    setLike(video) {
        this.likeservice.setLike(1, video.id).subscribe(
            () => video.isLiked = true
        );
    }

    revokeLike(video) {
        this.likeservice.revokeLike(1, video.id).subscribe(
            () => video.isLiked = false
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in `setLike` and  `revokeLike` functions, send a `video object` to `function` and `make` `isLiked` to change `accordingly`

This makes the `*ngIf` condition working for you.

**HTML:**

```
<mat-card-actions class="text-center">
    <button *ngIf="video.isLiked == true" mat-icon-button color="warn">
        <mat-icon (click)="revokeLike(1, video)">favorite</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <button *ngIf="video.isLiked == false" mat-icon-button class="grey_like">
        <mat-icon (click)="setLike(1, video)">favorite</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span>{{ competition.likesCount }} Likes</span>
</mat-card-actions>
```

**Component:**

```
setLike(iid, video) {
    this.likeservice.setLike(iid, video.id).subscribe(
        data => {
            video.isLiked = true;
        }
    );
}

revokeLike(iid, video) {
    this.likeservice.revokeLike(iid, video.id).subscribe(
        data => {
            video.isLiked = false;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, thank you very much, but Andrew answered just a moment before you.

Comment: its ok @MahmoodKohansal, whoever answers first, our goal is to help people. :-)